# How do I count all the values in a table and echo a some certain value if that value repeats itself certain number of times?

Tags: php, sql

I have a database of reservations that contains all of bookings, now I want to limit the dates if 1 date repeats itself certain number of times (for testing purposes, 5). I wrote a query that selects all the dates but figured it just counts all the dates not the dates with same values. How do I make it do that?

```php
$sql2 = "SELECT date FROM tbl_reservations ORDER BY date ASC";
$res2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);

if($res2 == TRUE)
{
    $count2 = mysqli_num_rows($res2); 

    if ($count2 > 5)
    {
        while ($rows2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res2))
        {
            $books = $rows2['date']; echo"\"$books\",";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write below query to select all dates (which were repeated specific amount of times, for example 5):

```
SELECT COUNT(date) AS numberofreservations, date FROM tbl_reservations GROUP BY date HAVING numberofreservations >= 5
```

Then you can check if the entered date is contained in the above selection, it means that date is full.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to group your reservations by date, and then use the count function to give you the number of records for each date.

```
SELECT COUNT(date) AS numberofreservations, date FROM tbl_reservations GROUP BY date
```

It may also be an idea to change the name of the date field to something like reservation_date, since date is a field type, and using that as a field name can lead to confusion (and some database engines will require the field name to be quoted, if it's a reserved word)